# How do I exclude a WordPress site from search engines and make it accessible only via password?

Tags: wordpress, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, security, password

The goal is to have a simple WordPress site for company employees to retrieve information that can be sensitive. The site is supposed to be online so it can be access by me from home, but needs to be excluded from every search engine and have a password login. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The safest way is to serve it behind a firewall that allows access from local IP addresses on your company's network, with an additional rule to allow access for your remote IP address.  You can also [Password Protect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection) your WorldPress posts. Both will prevent search engines from being able to crawl and index them. Other means such as using _robots.txt_ directives and NOINDEX meta and server headers are far less reliable since they'd still be accessible and crawable via links.

Answer (score 2):

Why not put a `HTTP auth` username and password on the site.  This is done using *.htaccess* and *.htpasswd* files if you want to do it manually and learn something.

Or as with most things WordPress, there is a plugin here: http://www.tech-otaku.com/blogging/securing-wordpress-login-using-http-authentication/.

Visitors will see something like this before they even get to the site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress plugins/tools available here, which will only allow those of your visitors who have the password to access your wordpress site. For instance you may use the plugins mentioned below:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-my-site/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/